# Using Ruby/rails variables in a mandrill template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp, mandrill

Is it possible to use your rails variables on a Mandrill template?

I have an app where a user gets notified via email on certain actions, and right now it's done with action mailer without using Mandrill so it's just a text email with no styling. Obviously, I'd prefer to use a mandrill template I already have to add some dynamic content via variables.. I see a ton of companies using variables in email notifications so i assume it's possible, i just haven't found many useful articles that explain how it's done. If you can point me towards a useful article or just answer the question it'd be really helpful! Right now, I already made the template using Mailchimp, then sent it to mandrill and it's ready for use. My app already has the Mandrill configurations and works properly (i use it for static email that don't include variables). All i really need to do is configure it to allow me to use variables.

Thanks in advance. Happy holidays and war eagle!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [merge tags](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-) in the Mandrill template, and then either `global_merge_vars` (all recipients) or `merge_vars` (per recipients) message options to populate the template.

It is not very exciting approach, but it works fine.

In short, the solution is to put tags like:

```
*|MYTAG|*
```

anywhere in the template. Then, the send calls just need to populate the right option. Here for all participants:

```
mandrill = Mandrill::API.new('my_api_key')
template_name = "my-template-name"
template_content = [] # See doc, not related to the issue at hand.
message = {
    to: [{email: 'smith@example.com'}],
    headers: {"Reply-To" => "noreply@example.com"},
    merge: true,
    global_merge_vars: [
      {name: 'mytag', content: "Hello, World"}
    ]
}
mandrill.messages.send_template(template_name, template_content, message)
```

This should send an email with the tag replaced with the corresponding contents (`Hello, World` here).